# Change the date time format in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I'm getting date and time from the api. I want to change the date and time format.

I'm getting like this "2016-05-12","07:17:35".

Change the format like 12-may-2016 7:30 PM:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Place</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="l in dataget">
        <tr>                    
            <td>{{l['time']}}</td>
            <td>{{l['place']}}</td>                             
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you getting date like this `"2016-05-12","07:17:35",` or `"2016-05-12 07:17:35"` this??

Comment: i'm getting like this [ "2016-05-12","07:17:35"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***controller.js**

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  myApp.filter('datetime', function($filter)
  {
    return function(input)
     {
      if(input == null){ return ""; } 
      var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input),
                          'MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss'); 
     return _date.toUpperCase();
 };
});
```

**In HTML**

```
<div ng-app="sampleapp">
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Place</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="l in dataget">
    <tr>                    
        <td>{{l['time'] | datetime}}</td>
        <td>{{l['place']}}</td>                             
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the date filter

```
<table class="table" ng-repeat="a in list_alerts">
<thead><tr>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Place</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="l in dataget">
<tr>                    
<td>{{l['time']| date : format}}</td>
<td>{{l['place']}}</td>                             
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

the format should be replaced with one of the possible accepted values, for the format that displays the desired output, check the possible values from angular api: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

here is an example that uses the 'short' format:

```
<table class="table" ng-repeat="a in list_alerts">
<thead><tr>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Place</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="l in dataget">
<tr>                    
<td>{{l['time']| date : 'short'}}</td>
<td>{{l['place']}}</td>                             
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), you need to write it like this:
`{{yourDate | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a'}}`. 

The result of this will be `12-May-2016 7:30 PM`

Answer (score 0):

Use date:format after object with pipe symbol.

[For Example Click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Answer (score 0):

I think this helps,

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.dateString = '"2016-05-12","07:17:35"';
    $scope.finalFormat = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.dateString.substring(1,11) +" "+ $scope.dateString.substring(14,22)),'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check date format https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date and use it like this:

```
{{your_date | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a'}}
```

Play with it here http://jsfiddle.net/vpfxdrum/. 
Using it in your case:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Place</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="l in dataget">
    <tr>                    
        <td>{{l['time'] | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a'}}</td>
        <td>{{l['place']}}</td>                             
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I want to change from ng-repeat